# Classic Pizza Hut Lettering - who designed it?

Tags: logo, branding, history

[image]

I can't seem to find any reference to who designed the classic pizza hut logo, although I swear I read it somewhere at some point. Specifically I'm interested in the lettering! Any help appreciated!

Comment: Some related info how it got the red top: http://blog.pizzahut.com/inside-the-hut/tbt-the-story-of-pizza-huts-red-roof/

Answer (score 3):

From [famouslogos.us](https://www.famouslogos.us/pizza-hut-logo/):

> **Pizza Hut** is one of the largest restaurant chains in the world, known for its different varieties of pizza and side dishes including pasta, salad, breadsticks and buffalo wings. Headquartered in Plano, Texas, it employs more than 30,000 in 95 different countries of the world.
>
> #### DESIGN ELEMENTS OF PIZZA HUT LOGO
>
> **Shape and Color of the Pizza Hut Logo**:
>
> The earliest Pizza Hut logo appeared on the signage on the first store of Pizza Hut in 1958. Based on a simple sans serif (?) typeface, it featured the company name “Pizza Hut” because the spaces on the signage were very limited as it merely had a space of 9 characters. When Pizza Hut saw Shakey’s Pizza, a competing chain that largely expanded on west coast at that time, **Dan and Frank Carney** decided to design a corporate identity for their company.
>
> They sought help from an architect named **Richard D. Burke** who built a mansard roof shape for their store. Based on the this development, the long-standing old emblem remained in use from 1967 to 1999.
>
> The current Pizza Hut logo was created in 2008 when Pizza Hut start to offer pasta items on their menu. The red color in the Pizza Hut logo represents freshness, whereas the yellow color depicts richness, taste and joy. The current revised logo was developed by Deutsch LA.